# if statement with function calls to optionals

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and working on migrating our Objective-C codebase to Swift.
I'm having a hard time finding a good way to do build a conditional with involving OR and method calls to optionals.

Say I have 2 objects 'ojb1' and 'obj2'

In Objective-C I can write:

```
return [obj1 booleanMethod] || [obj2 booleanMethod]
```

this would return true if any of the two objects are not nil and its method returns true.

in Swift I have to:

```
if let obj1 = obj1, obj1.booleanMethod() {
    return true
} else if let obj2 = obj2, obj2.booleanMethod() {
    return true
}
return false
```

or

```
return ((obj1 != nil && obj1!.booleanMethod()) || (obj2 != nil && obj2!.booleanMethod())
```

is there a better/cleaner/shorter way to do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, you can use `==` with optionals. This is a case where directly comparing a `Bool` to `true` is useful.

```
return obj1?.booleanMethod() == true || obj2?.booleanMethod() == true
```

In the case of the `nil` optional, the comparison to `true` will be false.

Comment: Thanks, I like this better as I find it easier to read than the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

In swift express `obj1` and `obj2` as 2 optionals , then try

```
return obj1?.booleanMethod() ?? false || obj2?.booleanMethod() ?? false
```